# Как сделать видео плеер на js не используя тег <video>

Tags: javascript

Дамы и Господа, есть два новых тега в `HTML5` это `<audio> и <video>`, но помимо 
 `HTML` можно в `js` создать объект `new Audio()` и далее управлять этим аудио объектом.

Вопрос: существует ли некий аналог `new Audio()` для создания видео объекта?

Сразу хочу отметить, что  `new Video()` не существует или я его не нашел))).
Хочу создать видео плеер на чистом `js` без тега `<video>`...

> P.S. Принимаются даже экспериментальные технологии

Comment: думаю вам надо начать делать и что не ясно спрашивать. пока не вижу сложности вообще. загружаем картинки и проигрываем их в режиме анимации. дорожку звука пускаем параллельно.

Comment: почему бы не использовать `document.createElement("video")` как аналог `new Audio()` ?

Comment: @webDev_ Ну и в чем разница?

Comment: @Air разница между чем?

Comment: @webDev_ между `document.createElement("video")` и  тегом `<video>`?

Comment: @Air, Думаю, что вы сами сможете ответить на вопрос о разнице - `console.log(new Audio());` что вы наблюдаете?

Comment: @Air так ведь нужно было управлять им в фоне без отображения, с этим объектом и можно будет работать за полем зрения точно так же, как и с `audio`. Если же планируется показать видео то без тега в `DOM` никак.

Comment: @webDev_ , я уже сделал плеер с тегом `<video>` стандартный контроль отключил, и управляю с помощью JS, я в курсе как это делается,   меня интересует есть ли именно объект аналог `new Audio()`

Comment: @Deonis разница не большая но есть...

Comment: @hitcode, какие картинки загружаем и куда и как проигрываем?

Comment: Конечно нет, сами напишите такую функцию, чтоб она создавала <video>, потом перехватывала управление над ним и добавляла в this все нужные функции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А вы уверены, что это вообще нужно? Ведь Audio создаёт объект, который проигрывает музыку, которым надо управлять из js. А видео в любом случае надо разместить на странице, просто, если хотите управлять им из js, не писать controls